# How to create jigsaw puzzle pieces using openGL and bezier curve?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, bezier

I am trying to create a jigsaw puzzle demo, and I would like to know of alternative ways of creating puzzle pieces without using mask. Currently I have jigsaw pieces by taking a full image, breaking that image up into four pieces (lets say the puzzle is 2x2) and then storing and applying a mask to each piece. It looks like the below

```
    // create standard puzzle pieces
    arryPieceEndPos = new int[mCols][mRows];
    arryPieceImg = new Bitmap[mCols * mRows];
    arryIsPieceLocked = new boolean[mCols * mRows];

    int pos = 0;
    for (int c = 0; c < mCols; c++) {
        for (int r = 0; r < mRows; r++) {
            arryPieceImg[pos] = Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmap,
            c * mPieceWidth, r * mPieceHeight,
            mPieceWidth, mPieceHeight);

            arryIsPieceLocked[pos] = false;
            arryPieceEndPos[c][r] = pos;
            pos++;
        }
    }
```

I then use a helper method to apply a mask to each piece

```
private Bitmap maskMethod(Bitmap bmpOriginal, Bitmap bmpMask) {

    // adjust mask bitmap if size is not the size of the puzzle piece
    if (bmpMask.getHeight() != mPieceHeight ||
        bmpMask.getWidth() != mPieceWidth) {
        Log.e("TEST", "Resize Error :: H (mask): " + bmpMask.getHeight() + " // W (mask): " +
            bmpMask.getWidth());
        Log.d("TEST", "Resize Error :: H (norm): " + mPieceHeight + " // W (norm): " +
            mPieceWidth);

    }

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    Bitmap combine = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmpOriginal.getWidth(), bmpOriginal.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    canvas.setBitmap(combine);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setFilterBitmap(false);

    canvas.drawBitmap(bmpOriginal, 0, 0, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmpMask, 0, 0, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(null);

    return combine;
}
```

I have been reading up on bezier curves and openGL. Neither of these I am very familiar with and they are very complex. I would like some help with forming a jigsaw puzzle piece, so that I can have an example of how it can be done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bezier curves can be complex, but we can "cheat" by defining the puzzle heads using Catmul-Rom curves first (which have the nice property of actually passing through their control points) and then trivially converting them to Bezier curves instead (since they're both plain Hermite splines).

So: let's do this. An example image: [image]

All we've done is split it up so far, using fairly simple rules. In sort-of-code (technically: [Processing](https://processing.org)):

```
int hx = width/4;
int hy = height/4;
for(int x = hx; x<width; x+=hx) {
  line(x,0,x,height);
  for(int y = hy; y<height; y+=hy) {
    line(0,y,width,y);
  }
}
```

And other than a fun image, it's not very exciting, so let's invent some puzzle joins. First off, we mark the centers of those cuts:

[image]

Again not really exciting:

```
for(int x = hx/2; x<width; x+=hx) {
  for(int y = hy/2; y<height; y+=hy) {
    ellipse(x + hx/2,y,5,5);
    ellipse(x,y + hy/2,5,5);
  }
}
```

But, we can make it exciting. For each of those centers, we can pick points to the left/right or up/down (depending on the edge) and decide whether to have the piece extend to the left or right, and then invent some points "around the center" to give us our Catmull-Rom curve:

[image]

```
for(int x = hx/2; x<width; x+=hx) {
  for(int y = hy/2; y<height; y+=hy) {
    // horizontal
    ellipse(x-5, y+hy/2, 2,2);
    ellipse(x+5, y+hy/2, 2,2);

    boolean up = random(1) < 0.5;
    if(up) {
      ellipse(x-random(5,10), y+hy/2 - random(10,20), 2,2);
      ellipse(x+random(5,10), y+hy/2 - random(10,20), 2,2);
    } else {
      ellipse(x-random(5,10), y+hy/2 + random(10,20), 2,2);
      ellipse(x+random(5,10), y+hy/2 + random(10,20), 2,2);
    } 

    // vertical
    ellipse(x+hx/2, y-5, 2,2);
    ellipse(x+hx/2, y+5, 2,2);
    boolean left = random(1) < 0.5;
    if(left) {
      ellipse(x+hx/2-random(10,20), y-random(5,10), 2,2);
      ellipse(x+hx/2-random(10,20), y+random(5,10), 2,2);
    } else {
      ellipse(x+hx/2+random(10,20), y-random(5,10), 2,2);
      ellipse(x+hx/2+random(10,20), y+random(5,10), 2,2);
    }       
  }
}
```

We're over-generating here, so I'll leave it to you to figure out how to prevent the "piece joiner" coordinates from being computed for the right-most and lowest-most edges (which should be fairly easy).

Now then: let's turn this into a coordinate grid, because that's looking pretty good, and we should get pretty nice piece joiners using Catmull-Rom:

[image]

Beauty.

```
for (int x = hx/2; x<width; x+=hx) {
  for (int y = hy/2; y<height; y+=hy) {
    // horizontal
    int xs = x-hx/2, 
        ym = y+hy/2, 
        xe = x+hx/2;
    float x3, x4, y1, y2,
          x1 = x-5, 
          x2 = x+5;

    boolean up = random(1) < 0.5;
    x3 = x - random(5, 10);
    x4 = x + random(5, 10);
    if (up) {
      y1 = y+hy/2 - random(10, 20);
      y2 = y+hy/2 - random(10, 20);
    } else {
      y1 = y+hy/2 + random(10, 20);
      y2 = y+hy/2 + random(10, 20);
    } 

    curve(xs, ym, x1, ym, x3, y1, x4, y2);         
    curve(x1, ym, x3, y1, x4, y2, x2, ym);         
    curve(x3, y1, x4, y2, x2, ym, xe, ym);

    // vertical
    int ys = y-hy/2, 
        xm = x+hx/2, 
        ye = y+hy/2;

    y1 = y-5; 
    y2 = y+5; 

    float y3, y4;

    boolean left = random(1) < 0.5;
    y3 = y - random(5, 10);
    y4 = y + random(5, 10);
    if (left) {
      x1 = x+hx/2 - random(10, 20);
      x2 = x+hx/2 - random(10, 20);
    } else {
      x1 = x+hx/2 + random(10, 20);
      x2 = x+hx/2 + random(10, 20);
    }

    curve(xm, ys, xm, y1, x1, y3, x2, y4);         
    curve(xm, y1, x1, y3, x2, y4, xm, y2);         
    curve(x1, y3, x2, y4, xm, y2, xm, ye);         
  }
}
```

It should be relatively obvious where you need to do perform your cuts to end up with these pieces now, but if you're working with a system that can't do Catmull-Rom but can only do Bezier curves, the conversion is really straight forward. The preceding code's been using

```
curve(x1,x2,y1,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4);
```

but that's a Catmull-Rom curve. To get the equivalent curve, [we can use a Bezier segment of the form](http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#catmullconv):

```
bezier(
  x2, y2,
  x2 - (x3-x1)/6, y2 - (y3-y1)/6, 
  x3 + (x4-x2)/6, y3 + (y4-y2)/6, 
  x3, y3
)
```

And let's get puzzling.

Comment: Great answer Mike, sorry I just saw this now.